# Debugging Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, debugging

I've been wondering, whenever Angular logs error it's a pile of gibberish similar to this:

```
Error: [ng:areq] Argument 'AppController' is not a function, got undefined
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.23/ng/areq?p0=AppController&p1=not%20a%20function%2C%20got%20undefined
    at http://localhost/NAME/vendors/angular/angular.js:78:12
    at assertArg (http://localhost/NAME/vendors/angular/angular.js:1509:11)
    at assertArgFn (http://localhost/NAME/vendors/angular/angular.js:1519:3)
    at http://localhost/NAME/vendors/angular/angular.js:7271:9
    at http://localhost/NAME/vendors/angular/angular.js:6663:34
    at forEach (http://localhost/NAME/vendors/angular/angular.js:332:20)
    at nodeLinkFn (http://localhost/NAME/vendors/angular/angular.js:6650:11)
    at compositeLinkFn (http://localhost/NAME/vendors/angular/angular.js:6098:13)
    at compositeLinkFn (http://localhost/NAME/vendors/angular/angular.js:6101:13)
    at compositeLinkFn (http://localhost/NAME/vendors/angular/angular.js:6101:13)
```

How do I know which line of **MY** code (not angular source code) triggered the error? Adding breakpoints or Batarang isn't helping.

## Edit

I don't have problem with this specific error. There are cases where angular logs a line number, say `Controller.js:1183:48`, and cases where it doesn't. **What makes the difference? And in latter cases, how do I find out MY error line?**

Answer (score 11, accepted):

1. If the problem is a run-time error inside one of your controllers you'll get the line number.
2. If it's a problem interpreting something inline `{{ like.this() }}` or a problem with an expression in a directive (ex: `ng-repeat='foo in undefinedBar'`), or any other expression not running inside a script tag or reference, then you'll get the line of code from the angular framework where the error was first encountered (usually either the directive itself or the core).
3. If one of your controllers simply doesn't parse due to incorrect syntax, it will tell you it can't even load the module. This also applies if there actually is a problem with how your app is set up, but I assume this question is for the times when you're trying to track down a hard-to-find error in a controller or view.

Usually when I experience #2 (most common source of frustration) I look for clues as to what type of error it is (maybe a collection wasn't defined if it tells me "length" was undefined, for instance). Usually the problem is tied to either bad syntax or my controller models not being in a state I expected.

Comment: so how do you FIND the source of the problem?  I don't want to spend hours looking for a single character mistake that ends up not being relevant to my current issue.  This answer doesn't answer the most important part of the question.

Comment: Not knowing the specific error (the question was not about the specific error listed) makes this impossible to answer completely.

Many times it's impossible to pinpoint a line of code based on a stack trace, and usually that's because angular has no way of reporting the line of your html view the inline expression broke on. But in these cases it should really be obvious enough that you can pinpoint the problem within a few pieces of code.

Using the un-minified version of AngularJS in debug adds on much more verbose logging too, which is usually helpful.

Comment: Also I'll add that the obvious solution is to make sure as many errors as possible occur in the pattern of #1. You can do this by limiting your use of complex inline expressions and instead deferring to controller functions to do any data transformations. Then you're just left making sure your syntax is correct for things like ng-repeat and ng-options. In cases where your view is so big that it actually takes "hours" to track down, I'd suggest reducing the size of your problem by adding more structure, but these are basic programming principles I expected the OP to have knowledge of already.

Answer (score 2):

You can click on :-

```
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.23/ng/areq?p0=AppController&p1=not%20a%20function%2C%20got%20undefined
```

This link ( 2nd line ) of the error. It would open the error description on the angular js website.

For example, in your case the error is :

```
Argument 'AppController' is not a function, got undefined
```

Which mean you have a typo in your controller or you have not made the controller at all. You can see this error once you click on that link.

Edit: 
If there is a error pertaining to your code like something undefined. You get a link to reach your code line as well. Following is a example of such a error, where a variable is undefined.

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'filetype' of undefined
    at Object.fn (http://localhost:8080/techpedia/js/Controller.js:1183:48)
    at k.$digest (http://localhost:8080/techpedia/js/angular.min.js:109:403)
    at k.$apply (http://localhost:8080/techpedia/js/angular.min.js:112:398)
    at http://localhost:8080/techpedia/js/angular.min.js:18:270
    at Object.d [as invoke] (http://localhost:8080/techpedia/js/angular.min.js:35:36)
    at c (http://localhost:8080/techpedia/js/angular.min.js:18:178)
    at fc (http://localhost:8080/techpedia/js/angular.min.js:18:387)
    at Xc (http://localhost:8080/techpedia/js/angular.min.js:17:415)
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (http://localhost:8080/techpedia/js/angular.min.js:214:144)
    at l (http://localhost:8080/techpedia/js/foundation.min.js:18:16937)
```

The link will point out the line number in your code.

```
http://localhost:8080/techpedia/js/Controller.js:1183:48
```

Comment: Thanks, I've done it, but it still doesn't point to the line number in MY code. Is there a way of tracing this?

Comment: I have edited my answer accordingly, your controller is missing. Either a typo or you have not included the file or something. Post some of your code, that would make things more clear. You can click on the 3rd line to get to the code as well.

Comment: I know what caused this particular error. I'm asking a general question. The 3rd line points to angular source code, not where MY code led to that line of angular code.

Comment: If there is a error pertaining to your code. You get that in the error as well. I will update the answer to show you one such example.

Comment: Thanks for the update. I have no problem finding out the error line in these cases. What about the cases like the one I posted above? What's the difference? Why doesn't these cases provide a line? How do I find it in these cases?

Comment: I cannot comment on this case. You did not get a line because you are using a (anonymous function) maybe ? 
Can you please share some code snippet ?

Comment: @Lucia what line in your code should trigger an error of an undefined controller? What would that help you?

Answer (score 0):

Verify if you properly defined AppController. Search `AppController` in your sources

Answer (score 0):

Base on that, the answer is you don't. This is one of the problems angularjs is trying to fix when developing javascript.

Their answer is a framework that offers or forces developers to code in easily testable javascript.